# Fill arrays in parent process through multithreading in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following situation

```py
    def f(foo, bar, i):
        foo[i] = 42
        bar[i] = 76

    foo, bar = [[]]*24, [[]]*24
    g = partial(f, foo=foo, bar=bar)

    ... Call f in a multi-threaded way and have foo and bar filled ...
```

Foo and bar in the parent process could also be filled with objects rather than numericals.

How should I go about and do this in a safe way

This code is enclosed in a class method.

Comment: The most reliable approach would be using a pipe or queue. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

Comment: you can use a [Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) to [share states between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: The function is inside of a class and I cannot enclose it in the __name__ == __main__.

Comment: whats the safe way you are refering?

Comment: No memory leak or crash

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you would like to do the best way would be to use a Queue object to allow the child threads of your main loop to be able to pull in objects as they need to. This has good information for how to control information between processes in multithreaded python:

https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html